# Word Cloud in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, word-cloud

everyone! I'm learning Visualization Data with Python and I got into a 'Word Cloud' tool. In the example, they do this:

```
`!wget --quiet https://s3-api.us-geo.objectstorage.softlayer.net/cf-courses-data/CognitiveClass/DV0101EN/labs/Data_Files/alice_novel.txt`


alice_novel = open('alice_novel.txt', 'r').read()
```

Why we use !wget -- quiet before the URL?

Comment: wget downloads the resources over the internet. --quite means don't print the messages or any output. So in summary it downloaded "alice_novel.txt" file at your current directory, and then your next line opens that file.